# How to read in Unicode code points into R data frame

Tags: r, unicode

I have a two-column text file of Unicode code points of interest (Greek symbols in this test, but any set of Unicode characters, generically):

```
$ cat ut.txt 
\u0391 Α
\u0392 Β
\u0393 Γ
\u0394 Δ
\u0395 Ε
\u0396 Ζ
...
```

I'd like to read this into R, so that I can kick the tires on the typeface I am using to make plots that contain mathematical or other Unicode symbols.

As a minimally-reproducible start, I start by drawing a random sample from this Unicode table:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(date = 1:10 , value = cumsum(runif(10 , max = 10)) )    
ut <- read.table("ut.txt", allowEscapes=TRUE)
df$labels <- paste("\\", sample(ut$V1, size=10), sep="")
```

The head of the data frame looks like this:

```
  date    value  labels
1    1  9.14806 \\u03A8
2    2 18.51881 \\u03BB
3    3 21.38021 \\u03C4
4    4 29.68469 \\u039C
5    5 36.10214 \\u03A6
6    6 41.29310 \\u03C2
```

When I plot from the `labels` column, R writes out the literal string, and not the Unicode character it represents:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=value, label=labels))
p <- p + geom_line()
p <- p + ggtitle("5\u03BCg (\u03C7-squared test)") # control title
p <- p + geom_text()
library(Cairo)
ggsave("test.pdf", device=cairo_pdf)
```

Here is what the test plot looks like:

[image: Test plot]

What I would like to see are Greek symbols at each point along the line, instead of their literal string equivalents.

How can I read a set of Unicode code points from a text file and use them directly?

***Important note**: I did test sampling from the second column of `ut.txt`, which works. However, I am specifically interested in learning what is required to correctly read in the encoded code point equivalent from a file*.

Comment: two answers with hand-coding, that's absurd. you can use `ut$V2` instead

Comment: As I said in the note, I was able to use `ut$V2`. My question is about using the first column.

Comment: `df$labels <- sprintf('"%s"', df$labels)` and `geom_text(parse = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach using `scale_shape_manual`. I included the code of how I entered your data so I didn't have to read the text file

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(date = 1:10 , value = cumsum(runif(10 , max = 10)) )    


df <- df[1:6, ]
## Following line stands in for what you read from `read.table`. In your solution, just use what you got from `read.table`
df$labels <- c("\u03A8", "\u03BB", "\u03C4", "\u039C", "\u03A6", "\u03C2")



library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=value, shape = labels))
p <- p + geom_line()
p <- p + ggtitle("5\u03BCg (\u03C7-squared test)") # control title
p <- p + geom_point(size = 5) + scale_shape_manual(values = df$labels)
p
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I should probably clarify: How do I read labels from a text file, as described in the original question? My question isn't about typing in a column vector's contents by hand.

Comment: My mistake, reading as `read.table(... , fileEncoding = "UTF-8")` works for me. Not clear to me that an extra line of code in the read is any better than an extra line of code in the plotting function, but that is up to you :)

Comment: It's definitely better than entering hundreds of symbols in by hand!

Comment: You don't have to enter them by hand! You just read in the codes and work with those (e.g. "\u03A8"), as you did when you provided the `head` of your dataframe. No manual entering needed at all

Comment: You were able to read in the codes right? (e.g. "\u03A8") So I provided a solution to work with those to get the special characters you want. I included a line where I enter the codes in a vector so I didn't have to create a text file and read it. Your read command would take the place of my vector code there. You can alternatively directly read the unicode characters (e.g. Δ), but it's basically the same amount of coding

Comment: The answer you provide above requires entering codes by hand. Can you edit it to what you think would work, when reading them in from a file? Then I can retest your answer.

Comment: Where is it you think I'm entering by hand? The line where I have `df$labels <- c("\u03A8",...)` is just a stand-in for what you would get from `read.table`. The `head` of the dataframe you supply in your question shows that you were able to read in those codes, so you can work directly with those to get the symbols

Comment: Then as I show in my comment, as an alternative approach you should be able to directly read in the special characters using `read.table(... , fileEncoding = "UTF-8")`. But neither approach requires entering anything by hand

Answer (score 0):

It also works with `geom_text()` (Infinite thanks to **@astrofunkswag** for its smart way to teach us how to include symbols properly):

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=value))+
  geom_line()+
  ggtitle("5\u03BCg (\u03C7-squared test)")+
  geom_text(label=c("\u03A8", "\u03BB", "\u03C4", "\u039C", "\u03A6", "\u03C2"))
```

Output:

[image]